# Python Pyro running on Linux to open a COM object on a remote windows machine, is it possible?

Tags: python, linux, windows, com, pyro

I have a project that requires the usage of COM objects running on a windows machine.
The machine running the Python Django project is on a Linux box. I want to use Pyro and the django App to call COM objects on the remote windows machine.
Is it possible? Any suggestion is appreciated?

Comment: Great question! Sadly, not directly. COM is a Native concept to Windows and is not easily, in a COM native capacity, called remotely into even when programming entirely on Windows... HOWEVER, maybe you can have the windows programmers wrap these COM objects in a RESTful or SOAP service using, then use Python Django calls to retrieve the data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a perfect use case for Pyro, to create a platform independent wrapper around your COM access code.

At least I assume you have some existing Python code (using `ctypes` or `pywin32`?) that is able to invoke the COM object locally? You wrap that in a Pyro interface class and expose that to your linux box.

I think the only gotcha is that you have to make sure you `pythoncom.CoInitialize()` things properly in your Pyro server class to be able to deal with the multithreading in the server, or use the non-threaded multiplex server.